# Salesforce DX Trail - scratch org is not found locally

Tags: salesforcedx, trailhead

I've been following this trail here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx/create-and-test-our-scratch-org?trail_id=sfdx_get_started and have run all the commands , where I am stopped is this part here:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a dreamhouse-org
```

then I've run

```
sfdx force:org:open
```

Which opens the org just fine in the UI.  But when I run

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project. ! This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project.
```

when I do a directory listing , all I see in that folder is the /config folder that contains the scratch file.  Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: You need to be running these commands within the clone of the Dreamhouse project. There should be more in there than the `config` folder - you should see a `force-app` folder and other support files.

Comment: Indeed, the `force-app` folder wasn't there.  I deleted the project and set it up anew and now everything works.

Comment: I'll re-post as an answer - glad that turned out to be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFDX will run certain commands regardless of your current working directory, but `force:source` commands have to be run in the context of a Salesforce DX project.

For the Trailhead module, one needs to be running these commands within the clone of the Dreamhouse project from GitHub. Within that folder, you should have `config`, but also a `force-app` source tree, as well as other support files. If they're missing, re-cloning could be the solution; if not, you may simply need to `cd` into the root project folder.